# How to disable notification from Pr that I'm not the assignee or owner?

Tags: github

I was added as a reviewer to a GitHub pull request and then I was removed, but I still get the notifications for that PR!!
How to disable notification from Pr that once I was one of the reviewers but now I'm not?

Comment: You should be able to unsubscribe from the thread. There is a button on the right when you open of the PR under notifications.

Comment: Thanks indeed @AndreiTumbar can you please post it as the answer?